# During SSIS execution, how do I view the Errors?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I cannot view the error as it cuts off in visual studio. Is there a window that I am missing out on? At the moment, I have been copying and pasting the error in a notepad so that I can see the actual error message.

[image]

Comment: This is still the case in VS 2017 & SSIS/SSDT. I can see truncated errors in Progress, but nothing in the Error List. Right-click on the error in Progress and paste into Notepad reveals the full error. Not sure how Windows developers can live like this. Painful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the View -> Error List will show you things wrong with your package at design time.

What you're seeing on the Results tab, the run-time information, is also going to be available to you in the `Output` window View -> Output or Ctrl+Alt+O for those who prefer keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to look at the errorlist.
View -> ErrorList

Or you can put debug points at various intervals and catch it that way and see a whole lot of information.

Unless you are looking for something else, this is the basic error output you get from SSIS.

Comment: When I view the Error List, I cannot see anything. The above is a screenshot from the "Progress" view where I can see what has happened. Essentially, what I'm looking for is a way to view the error after a certain task when I'm debugging this. Because the above doesn't really give much as it cuts off after a certain number of character and I have to copy and paste the error.

Comment: [This article should be of help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304419.aspx)  The complexity of the package is certainly a major factor. But that shouldn't hinder you from debugging most tasks within SSIS and getting the error out.

Answer (score 0):

Menu Option View | Output.

But..

It seems that the Flat File Source component can have an error but no error shows in the Output window.

e.g.
[image]

Comment: Has the same problem. Importing a flat file to a ADO NET DESTINATION. For the first time  it worked. Now second time is an error. but no errors on the Error List.